# Identify the attestation certificate (X.509) in Fido U2F registration response

Tags: authentication, certificates

I'm trying to identify the attestation certificate (X.509) in **Fido U2F** registration response as described in [fido-u2f-raw-message-formats-v1.0-rd-20141008.pdf](http://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-raw-message-formats-v1.0-rd-20141008.pdf) document:

> **An attestation certificate** [variable length]. This is a certificate in X.509 DER format. Parsing of the X.509 certificate unambiguously establishes its ending. - page 5

I need to know how can I get its length and identify all its fields.

Comment: it looks like you simply need a x.509 parser - you will have to look for one in the language you are using

Comment: Yes, But Before parsing it I have to select its field from Token response. as specified in Fido document It has a variable length but they didn't specify how many bytes in its length variable. for example :A key handle length byte **[1 byte]** i.e one byte specify the key handle length

Comment: ok - then this isn't an InfoSec question (or even a x.509 question), this is a question for Fido and their message format. There isn't much we can help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The U2F Raw Message Formats document [specifies](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-u2f-v1.0-nfc-bt-amendment-20150514/fido-u2f-raw-message-formats.html#registration-response-message-success) that the attestation certification is encoded using the [Distinguished Encoding Rules (DER)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding). The DER are [Tag-Length-Value (TLV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value) style binary encoding. Thus, you only have to read the first DER unit - and only the TL part of it (i.e. just a few bytes). Decoding the TL part of it gives you the remaining length of the certificate.